# php+html multiple row submit with checkbox filter

Tags: php, html

I created a page for multiple rows submit data to mysql with php!

But, I need filter check the `checkbox[]` has been `checked` for submit **current row data**

In my demo,
If I checked the row2 and row3, I expected I will get  `id=2` & `id=3`
finally I get the `id=1` & `id=2`

In the same situation, if I checked row3 only, I will get the `id=1`

I probably understand the principle, but I really can’t find a solution

```php
<?php

$row = "";
if ($_POST) {
    foreach ($_POST["checked"] as $key => $v) {
        if (@$_POST['checked'][$key] == "on") {
            $row[$key]['id'] = $_POST['id'][$key];
            $row[$key]['other_value'] = $_POST['other_value'][$key];
        }
    }
}
print_r($row);

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]">
    <input type="text" name="id[]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[]" value="a">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]">
    <input type="text" name="id[]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[]" value="b">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]">
    <input type="text" name="id[]" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[]" value="c">
  </p>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I try  @CBroe

if checked row3, I still get `a`

```php
<?php

$row = "";
if ($_POST) {
    foreach ($_POST["checked"] as $key => $v) {
        $row[$key]['checkbox'] = $_POST['checkbox'][$key];
        $row[$key]['other_value'] = $_POST['other_value'][$key];
    }
}
print_r($row);
?>

<form action="" method="POST" >
<p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="checked[]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[]" value="a">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="checked[]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[]" value="b">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="checked[]" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[]" value="c">
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the `id[]` field, and give the checkboxes the ID as value instead.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, but if give the checkboxes the ID. How to check the `checked status` ?

Comment: Only checked checkboxes are included in the form submission data set to begin with.

Comment: I tried it. But still the same situation, I had change the topic content

Comment: Trying to access the text field values with the same key as the checkboxes were submitted under, is still wrong - _because_ only the checked boxes will be submitted. So automatically created indexes will diverge here. You can fix this by _specifying_ the index to use upfront, instead of letting PHP generate it automatically - put it into the field names to begin with, `name="foo[0]"` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) Thanks for your

```php
<?php

$row = "";
if ($_POST) {
    foreach ($_POST["id"] as $key => $v) {
        $row[$key]['id'] = $_POST['id'][$key];
        $row[$key]['other_value'] = $_POST['other_value'][$key];
    }
}
print_r($row);

?>

<form action="" method="POST" >
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[1]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[1]" value="a">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[2]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[2]" value="b">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[3]" value="3">
    <input type="text" name="other_value[3]" value="c">
  </p>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```